# How to set font size in standalone class globally or locally?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, circuitikz

How can I set the font size for the standalone class globally or locally (as probably in some place you may need to increase or reduce size to make it fit)? I have copied the three `\renewcommand` from IEEEtran.cls for the Times New Roman font.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[american]
   \draw(0,0) to[R, v=$V_x$, name=R] ++(2,0); 
   \node at (1,1)  {${V_\mathrm{DC}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the standard modifiers either globally or locally:

```latex
\documentclass[]{standalone} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}

\begin{document}
\LARGE % globally change the size
\begin{tikzpicture}[american]
   \draw(0,0) to[R, v=$V_x$, name=R] ++(2,0);  
   \node[font=\tiny] at (1,1)  {${V_\mathrm{DC}}$};
   % or even inside the text of the node...
   \node[font=\tiny] at (1,.5)  {\normalsize ${V_\mathrm{DC}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]